# Error: error:areq Bad Argument

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("xPlat.controller", [])
    .controller('logInController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.login = function () {
            var request = $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:4309/Account/Login",
                data: ""
            }) 
        }
    }])
})();
```

And one HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="xPlat">
    <div ng-controller="logInController">
        <input type="text" placeholder="UserName" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" />
        <button ng-click="login()">Log In</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <!-- CordovaToDoApp_AngularJS references -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/controllers/logInController.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I build and run this application, I got an error message "Error: [ng:areq]" and link, when I click that link, I see a message " Argument 'logInController' is not a function, got undefined ". How to fix this problem? Thank

Comment: There is a name missmatch in module. `xPlat` vs `xPlat.controller`

Comment: You mean ng-app="xPlat" in HTML and xPlat.controller in Module?

Comment: There should be a module declared with the same name as defined on ng-app.

Comment: I've tried to declare with the same name, but it still got an undefined

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an xPlat moduel with xPlat.controller as dependency?

```
angular.module ('xPlat', [xPlat.controller]);
```

Alternatively, you may want to use xPlat as your module and not xPlat.controller, in this case the 
3rd line above should be:

```
angular.module("xPlat", [])
```

also make sure you upgrade angular to latest (1.2.26) if possible. In 1.2.23 they had few glitches on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: hope it will do work

```
var app=angular.module ('xPlat', [xPlat.controller]); 

app.controller("logInController", function () {
        alert('Done!!')
    });
```